# How to rotate an image inside bounding rectangle box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, rotation, geometry

I have the following img that I'd like to drag (by dragging a circle on top of rectangle) and rotate an image.

[image: Rectangle box with image inside it]

When dragging, I just want to rotate an image inside the rectangle and not the rectangle itself. I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly, I have this formula when I start dragging:

`const newAngle = Math.atan(circleDrag.y, circleDrag.x) * (180 / Math.PI);`

I'm getting the position of the circle from the top of the rectangle, but it's giving me something between `90` to `110` degrees only. Correct way of rotation angle would start from `0` I think, and should rotate between `0-360` degrees.

Could somebody direct me on how to calculate rotation angle?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs right, you have to measure angle of direction from the center point of rectangle to the circle center.

```
Math.atan(circleDrag.y - rectangleCenter.y, circleDrag.x - rectangleCenter.x)
```

*(At this moment you are calculating direction from coordinate origin to the circle)*